# How do I keep Score in Python?

Tags: python, if-statement

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnGxi.png)I don't know how to make python keep score in a game, I saw that I should put score = 0 at the top of code and then after the if statement put score +1 but it comes out blank whenever I run the code:[image]

I tried score +1 and score+=1 after the if statement but when I run it keeps coming out as blank.

Does anyone know how to help?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't use images to show your code, include it in the question as code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
    score = 0
    player_input = input("Enter the capital of Greece: ").capitalize()
    if player_input == "Athens":
        score += 1
    print(score)

    # I hope this helps
```

EDIT: Your use of .upper() will change a string like "text" into "TEXT". Instead I used .capitalize() which changes a string like "text" into "Text". Also instead of writing "score + 1", which doesn't actually add one to your score variable, you should write either "score = score + 1" or "score += 1" for short.